# How to reference control in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using asp.net and vb.net. How can I refer to my web user control instance ServiceForm? Do I need an ID or name somewhere?

Should it be My.Setting.ServiceForm or something like that?

```
For Each li As ListItem In cblServices.Items
    If li.Selected Then
        PnlServiceForms.Controls.Add(Page.LoadControl("ServiceForm.ascx"))
        'Access this instance of ServiceForm.aspx control - How? - ServiceForm1, ServiceForm2, etc?
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Page.LoadControl` returns a reference to the instance of the control.  (See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.templatecontrol.loadcontrol) for details.)  So you can store that in a variable:

```
Dim control As ServiceForm = Page.LoadControl("ServiceForm.ascx")
PnlServiceForms.Controls.Add(control)
' Here you can access your instance from the "control" variable
```

If you need to, you could also make it a class-level variable or whatever other scope is approapriate in your scenario.